# Is it possible to override dll in runtime in Qt?

Tags: qt, dll, runtime

I have an Qt application, which uses 2 dll, one is Prmt.dll and the other is Core.dll.
Core.dll is dependent on Prmt.dll.
Prmt.dll has multiple instances in different folders, for example: A/Prmt.dll, B/Prmt.dll...
The Qt application provides an option to choose Prmt.dll, so it need to override Prmt.dll in runtime.
Is it possible to override dll in runtime in Qt?

Comment: Have you tried to set the library directory instead of plugin file path?

Comment: I am totally new to Qt plugin or QtLibrary, so I have no idea about your question. Thanks!